# Coldfusion cfqueryparam - changing encoding?

Tags: sql-server-2016, coldfusion-2018

When running a query with EncryptByKey and cfqueryparam, the value appears to be getting truncated.

For example:

```
<cfset customer_number = 123 /> 
<cfset soc_sec_number = "123-45-6789" />

<cfquery datasource="web_applications">
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSNKey
        DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE SSNCert;

    UPDATE 
        Customers

    SET 
        
        SSN_Encrypted = EncryptByKey( Key_GUID( 'SSNKey' ), <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#soc_sec_number#" >   )
        

    WHERE 
        customer_number = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#customer_number#" > ;


        CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SSNKey;
</cfquery>
```

The resulting database value, when decrypted, is "1". If I remove the `<cfqueryparam>`, the whole value is stored without issue. Additionally, this issue only occurs when used in conjunction with `EncryptByKey`.

We're using CF 2018 and sql 2016. This just began to be a problem yesterday. It may or may not be related, but our power was lost yesterday. Is is possible that some cf file was corrupted, or some encoding setting was changed? How would I check for this?

UPDATE:

When performing the following query:

```
<cfquery name="get_ssn">
     OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSNKey
                DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE SSNCert;

            SELECT      
                CONVERT( VARCHAR, DecryptByKey( [ssnEncrypted] ) ) AS decrypted_ssn
                
            FROM        
                customers
            
            WHERE 
                Customer.customer_number= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#customer_number#" >  ;
           
            CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SSNKey;
</cfquery>
```

The resulting value of `decrypted_ssn` is as follows:

```
<cfdump var="#get_ssn.decrypted_ssn#"> -> 123-45-6789 
<cfdump var="#right(get_ssn.decrypted_ssn, 4)#"> -> 89

in sql studio -> 1
```

I suspect some encoding issue at this point, since coldfusion returns the full value but thinks that `right(123-45-6789, 4)` is `89` rather than `6789`

I'm not sure how to test this theory.

UPDATE:

I've confirmed this issue is arising on more than one table, and with more than one symmetric key.

UPDATE again:
The string saved using `cfqueryparam`, when the `LEN()` command is used, outputs 22, whereas the value WITHOUT `cfqueryparam` outputs 11.

UPDATE:
I followed the solution [Here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion/cfml-query-update-database-poland-character/td-p/8488407), which seemed to resolve my issue. But I want to understand how this happened. The connection didn't seem to require this until yesterday, when the power went out and the server restarted.

Comment: If you output the ascii values of the two strings char by char (len 22 and 11) what are they? Obviously don't post the ascii of the real ssn's :) Anything changed in the dsn settings?

Comment: @SOS So I tried a few different methods of output. It looks normal if I output it directly to the page. However, if I put the value inside of an input tag, it looks like this: 1�2�3�-�4�5�-�6�7�8�9� - Again, this is only if I update the table value with cfqueryparam, in conjunction with EncryptByKey.
Edit: I did find a solution, which I added to my answer, but I don't understand how this could have happened.

Comment: So what DSN setting did you end up changing - enabling "String Format - Enable High ASCII characters..." or adding "useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8...", etc to the connection string?

Comment: @SOS adding "useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8"